# How to model glass with octogonal base and cylindrical top?

Tags: modeling

I'm struggling about how to model this kind of cup. How should I do it ?

This cup is something like a cylinder, with ends are straight edges with different resolutions

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I'm not completely sure about the transition between the sharp faces and the circular part but basically you can try it this way:

Create a 8 vertex circle, subdivide it 7 times:

[image]

Keep only 1/8, array it around an empty:

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

Create the mid-edge, apply the *Array*, round the top edge with *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Create another edge, round it with *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Begin to scale the edge loops, add some new ones:

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: This is my attempt, but I feel like it would require a whole tutorial. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RiniLfwO4dYCLiLi2HLoKabjEU16VmWB/view?usp=sharing Should I upload the blend?

Comment: this looks good, you should propose your answer, are you sure about the circle in the middle though?

Comment: I can't know for sure; but, in my experience, that is how similar types of glasses are shaped. You could also model the lower interior to be octagonal, but that would be more work. Usually the transition to the thicker material is not that noticeable once there is liquid inside.

Comment: please submit your answer, I'm curious to know how you did it

Comment: Excellent! This is what I looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

[image]

## Step 1.

### Prepare reference Image

- Change the outliner to an image editor by pressing <kbd>**Shft**</kbd><kbd>**F9**</kbd>.
- Drag and drop the reference image onto your desktop.
- Drag and drop the reference image into the outliner.

---

## 2.

### Add a Circle

- Press <kbd>**Shft**</kbd><kbd>**A**</kbd>, <kbd>**M**</kbd>, <kbd>**R**</kbd>.
- Set Vertices to 8.
- Set Fill Type to Triangle Fan.
  [image: Add Circle]

---

## 3.

### Delete Redundant Geometry

- Press <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> to enter edit mode.
- Deselect the vertices of one triangle.
- Press <kbd>**X**</kbd>, <kbd>**V**</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> to exit edit mode.
  [image: Delete Redundant Geometry]

---

## 4.

### Add a Circular Array

- Press <kbd>**Shft**</kbd><kbd>**A**</kbd>, <kbd>**E**</kbd>, <kbd>**P**</kbd> to add an empty.
- Press <kbd>**R**</kbd>, <kbd>**Z**</kbd> and type `45`.
  (or use the middle mouse button to select an axis)
  [image: Add a Circular Array]
- Select the triangle and navigate to the modifiers section of the properties panel.
- Click on Add Modifier and press <kbd>**A**</kbd> to add the Array modifier.
- Configure the modifier as shown.
  [image: Add a Circular Array 2]

---

## 5.

### Model

- Select the two outer vertices.
- Press <kbd>**W**</kbd>, <kbd>**S**</kbd>, <kbd>**F9**</kbd>
- Change the number of cuts to `2`.
  [image: Model]
- Press <kbd>**E**</kbd>, <kbd>**Z**</kbd> to begin extruding upward to match the reference (about 2.25 times the radius).
  [image: Model 2]
- Add another circle.
- Set the Vertices to `24` (3*8).
- Set the Fill Type to Nothing.
  [image: Model 3]
- Delete the redundant geometry again.
  [image: Model 4]
- Select what remains by hovering over a remaining vertex and pressing <kbd>**L**</kbd>.
  [image: Model 5]
- Move it up about 4.5 times the radius.
  [image: ![Model 6]
- Extrude downward leaving a mid-sized gap as shown.
  [image: Model 7]
- Press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd><kbd>**E**</kbd>, <kbd>**L**</kbd> to join the parts.
  [image: Model 8]
- Press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd><kbd>**R**</kbd> to add a support loop below the transition.
  [image: Model 9]
- Move the six vertices in the middle up about this far.
  [image: Model 10]
- Add these edge loops. Use <kbd>**E**</kbd> to align with neighboring edge loops and <kbd>**F**</kbd> to flip which one is used for alignment if necessary.
  [image: Model 11]
  (The object has been darkened to increase visibility.)
- Change to face select mode by pressing <kbd>**3**</kbd> above the keypad or by selecting it from the viewport header.
- Press <kbd>**I**</kbd>, <kbd>**B**</kbd> to inset the bottom face without affecting the border.
  [image: Model 12]
- In vertex select mode, select the bottom, center vertex.
- Press <kbd>**Z**</kbd> to toggle wireframe mode.
- Move the vertex up until it looks good.
  [image: Model 13]
- In face select mode, select the bottom, center face.
- Inset the face two more times as shown.
  [image: Model 14]
- In edge select mode, press <kbd>**G**</kbd>, <kbd>**G**</kbd> to move the middle edge about halfway back as shown.
  [image: Model 15]
- In vertex select mode, select the two vertices shown.
- Press <kbd>**J**</kbd> to join them with an edge, splitting the ngon into a quad and a tri.
  [image: Model 16]
- Press and hold <kbd>**.**</kbd> on the main keypad, drag the cursor to the right, and release to switch the pivot point to the 3D cursor.
  [image: Model 18]
- Hold <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> and click one of the top edges to select the loop.
- Press <kbd>**E**</kbd>, <kbd>**S**</kbd>, <kbd>**Shft**</kbd><kbd>**Z**</kbd> to extrude and scale inward in the XY plane.
  [image: Model 19]
- Click the [image: Model 20] icon on the array modifier to disable the modifier in edit mode.
- Pres <kbd>**E**</kbd>, <kbd>**Z**</kbd> and extrude straight down a small distance as shown.
  [image: Model 21]
- Angle the view as shown to see the profile more easily.
  [image: Model 21]
- Extrude straight down to just above the transition.
  [image: Model 22]
- Extrude two more times as shown.
  [image: Model 23]
- Press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd><kbd>**+**</kbd> on the numpad to grow the selection.
  [image: Model 24]
- Scale inward along the XY plane so that there is a gap between the inner and outer surfaces.
  [image: Model 25]
- Press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd><kbd>**-**</kbd> on the numpad to shrink the selection.
- Press <kbd>**E**</kbd>, <kbd>**Shft**</kbd><kbd>**Z**</kbd>, <kbd>**0**</kbd> to extrude and scale to the center along the XY plane.
  [image: Model 26]
- Add edge loops as shown.
  [image: Model 27]
  (To add multiple equally spaced loops, scroll the mouse wheel or type the desired number.)
- Add a simple deform modifier.
  [image: Model 28]
- Configure the modifier as shown.
  [image: Model 29]
- Exit edit mode, apply the array modifier, and delete the empty.
  [image: Model 30]
- Enter edit mode again and disable the simple deform modifier.
- In face select mode, select the area shown.
  [image: Model 31]
- In vertex select mode, deselect the middle vertices as shown.
  [image: Model 32]
- Press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd><kbd>**B**</kbd> and adjust the width of the bevel.
- Before confirming, scroll up once to change the number of segments to two.
- Also before confirming, press <kbd>**P**</kbd> and type `1` to set the profile.
- Okay, you can confirm now.
  [image: Model 33]
- Exit edit mode.
- Hover over the array modifier and press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd><kbd>**A**</kbd> to apply it.
- With the cursor in the viewport, press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd><kbd>**2**</kbd> to add a subdivision surface modifier.
- Press <kbd>**W**</kbd>, <kbd>**S**</kbd> to shade smooth.
- If the shading doesn't look right, press <kbd>**Shft**</kbd><kbd>**N**</kbd> in edit mode.

---

## Presto!

[image: Final Image]

[image]

Comment: Gorgeous result. Only problem, I had to scroll for about 20 minutes to UV it ! :D

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking next time I should make it less beginner friendly lol.

Comment: @Robin I think it nicely builds a suspense that way :). I felt like I earned the final result...

Comment: nice! it could not be more detailed, longest scroll in BSE, ah ah